# Display child-page links in sidebar on both Parent Pages AND Child Pages

Tags: wordpress

I am currently developing a WordPress website that has a sidebar on most of the pages, this sidebar is supposed to display a small navigation of any child pages that are under the current parent page that is being viewed, along with two of the most recent posts.

I am having trouble with having the links to display on the sidebar, currently; they are only displaying on the main parent pages of the site and not on the child pages which is what I need.

I have created the following:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

<section class="links border shadow">

    <ul>

        <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>


        <li class="child-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>


            <?php

                    $args2 = array(
                        'post_type'      => 'page',
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                        'order'          => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
                     );


                    $parent2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

                    if ( $parent2->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $parent2->have_posts() ) : $parent2->the_post(); ?>

            <div id="sub-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="child-sub">

                <p class="sub-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                        title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </li>

        <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

</section>
```

I also stumbled across this snippet of code from another question on here; which does the same thing (only displays on parent pages), but also displays a link to the actual parent page too.

```
<?php
        if($post->post_parent){
            $children = get_pages("child_of=".$post->post_parent);
            $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
            $link = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
        }
        else{
            $children = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
            $parent_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
            $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
            $parent_page = $post->ID;
        }
        if ($children) {
        ?>
            <li <?php if( !empty($parent_page) && $parent_page==$post->ID){echo 'class="current-menu-item"';} ?>><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
            <?php 
                foreach( $children as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
            ?>
                    <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID)){echo 'class="current-menu-item"';} ?>>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
            <?php 
                endforeach;
            ?>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Current Parent Page (How I want all pages to look)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fixed the issue for me:

```
<?php
switch ($isBlogsPostPage){
    case true:
        $parentID=get_correct_id($post, $isBlogsPostPage);
        break;
    default:
        $parentID=get_correct_id($post);
}


$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_parent'    => $parentID,
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );
$parent = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( true ) : ?>

    <section class="links border shadow">
        <ul>
            <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();?>

                    <li class="child-title <?php if ((is_page(get_the_ID())) || (get_the_ID()===(int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) && $isBlogsPostPage)) echo ('active'); ?>">
                        <a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php /*endif;*/ wp_reset_postdata(); ?>    
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```